# Remove all files not listed by lsof in a folder

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

Recently I am writing a bash command-line script for maintaining the size of a specific folder. Note that some programs are at times writing/updating files inside this folder, so a "catch-all" rm -rf will never suit the case.

I am able to retrieve all the "active", in other words, open files using lsof and print them out with awk:

```
lsof +D ./ | awk ' { print ( $NF ) } '
```

This gives me a list of those open files, I obviously DON'T want to get rid of them. However I'd like to remove the rest.

I wish there is an option in the rm command to exclude some files using the ^ option...

Is there a way to achieve this in bash?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why don't you want to remove open files? They won't cause any problems for the programs with open handles (they'll be able to read and/or write as if they still existed), and the space will just be reclaimed automatically when they close them.

Comment: @Cairnarvon  because these files are for logging/tracing purpose and by business rules we should keep them intact.

Comment: You should probably whitelist those files explicitly instead of hoping none of your processes are down unexpectedly when cleaning out your folder, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have `extglob` on:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Then remove all files not listed in `lsof`:

```
DONT_RM=`lsof +D \. | awk '{ print $NF; }' | tr "\\n" "|" | sed 's/\.\///g'` && rm !($DONT_RM)
```

Breaking down the above, we're joining the results of `lsof` with pipes `|` instead of newlines `\n` and remove the prefacing `./` from the beginning of the filenames.  Then we pass this OR list of files to rm as a not `!` extglob option.  Try it out, it works in my basic tests.

Comment: really nice work done in one-line! Thanks for this so much, picked up some useful tips in your demo.

Answer (score 4):

This could be done on one line without temp files, but I'll split it up to make commenting and debugging easier:

```
# Get a sorted list of used files
lsof +D ./ | awk ' { print ( $NF ) } ' | sort | uniq > usedFiles

# Get a sorted list of existing files
find ./ | sort > existingFiles

# Find lines unique to existingFiles
comm -23 existingFiles usedFiles > removableFiles

# Delete them
rm $(< removableFiles)
```

Note that this is not white space safe.

Comment: emmm I have also worked out in a bash script way. I am using a for loop and test for each file in this directory if it is not open then remove it.